# Should I refetch data after every POST request?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am building a React / Redux app that allows users to post articles, that later are reviewed by a tech lead.

I often find myself writing code like that

```js
if(response.ok) {
  dispatch(saveAllPosts()) // this fetches all posts and saves them to redux store
  history.push("/") // redirects to main page with all posts listed
}
```

Is this a proper way of doing things?

Sometimes I think that this is my personal anti-pattern.

Should I be updating the redux store after successful POST request, rather than fetching the data again?

Comment: If you already have all the previous posts and have just created the new post, you already have all the data you need on the front end - just append the new post to the existing posts in the store, there's no need to fetch all the data again. If posts can be created on a different client (2 people creating posts on different PCs at once), to keep the store up to date, you might want to include some websockets or polling.

Comment: If it doesn’t break anything there doesn’t seem to be any reason why you can’t do it this way. Think about what the pros and cons of your pattern allow you to do. Fetching after every post request allows you to keep current state after every user action: this is fine so long as you’re not fetching something that takes noticeable time to resolve. If it does take a long time then this is not a way you should go. Perhaps look into background fetching and using async sockets to do the task instead.

Comment: It's a small app and it will stay that way, so there won't be too much data to fetch. I will look into sockets anyway, as it sounds interesting and I've never worked with this technology before. Thanks, guys.